# Is there any bias choosing a random number $1\ldots n$ in C as $1+(\mbox{rand}()\%n)$

Tags: random, programming

I need random numbers $1\ldots n$ in a program written in **C**. The library **rand()** function returns numbers in the range $0\ldots\mbox{RAND_MAX}$, where $\mbox{RAND_MAX}$ is typically $\sim2^{31}-1$. So I've just been taking $1+(\mbox{rand}()\%n)$ as a random number $1\ldots n$ (where **C** syntax $i\%j$ denotes "$i$ modulo $j$", the remainder after dividing $i$ by $j$). That is, equivalently, if we wrote the result of $\mbox{rand}()$ in base $n$, then I'd just take the low-order digit (plus one) as my random number.

Is this procedure just as random as $\mbox{rand}()$, or have I introduced any kind of bias?

Comment: No bias If **rand()** is uniform on $0,...,\mbox{RAND_MAX}$ it will be uniform on every subinterval of length $n$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks.

Comment: Even though rand() might be uniform (and presumably it is), I do not believe that rand()%n is uniform.  Unless rand_max is a multiple of n, every value rand() produces above (rand_max // n)*n would bias your results low in a stepwise constant distribution at a certain threshold value, rand_max%n.  This could be negligible.

Comment: @SquishyRhode Also, thanks. For my purposes, $n$ is typically $\sim10^2-10^4$, whereas RAND_MAX is typically $\sim10^9$, so I don't think there'd be that kind of problem. I had considered using instead something like 1 + (int)((double)n*((double)rand()/(1.0+(double)RAND_MAX))), but that seemed more complicated than I hoped would be necessary.

Comment: I havent actually analyzed this problem thoroughly so I could be wrong. But I dont think the sizes themselves of the ranges are relevant; you seem to think they are judging by your response.  Relative size is, perhaps.  I hope for your sake that youre right.  You are going to have to decide what a significant deviation is. But Im only answering the question: its not uniform, in the strictest sense.